# R: predict() for zero-inflated model does not return se.fit

Tags: r, model, predict, confidence-interval, standard-error

I am trying to compute **Confidence Intervals** for **zero-inflated models** which have been set up using the function zeroinfl()

If I compute them from a linear model or GLM using the function

```
predict(glm, newdata, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)
```

it works fine and returns values for $fit, $se.fit, $df and $residual.scale (I don't know what the two last outputs stand for - clarifications on that are much appreciated as well).

However, when I replace the glm with a zero-inflated model, I only get the values for $fit.

Here an example:
(I don't know how to use set.seed - so don't blame me on that)

```
set.seed(123)
a <- data.frame(participant = c(1:10),
                activity = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)))), 
                METmin = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)))),
                Var4 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)))),
                Var5 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)))))

b <- data.frame(participant = c(1:10),
                     activity = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)))), 
                     METmin = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)))),
                     Var4 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)))),
                     Var5 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)))))
identical(a,b) #FALSE
model <- zeroinfl(METmin~activity + Var4 + Var5, data = a)
predict(model, newdata = b, type = "response", se.fit = T)
```

Does anyone know what goes wrong here and how I can compute these standard errors?

Thank you so much.

Comment: @MrFlick I edited the question above.

Comment: $df stands for degrees of freedom. I'm not familiar with residual.scale, however residuals are usually plotted to see if it is randomly dispersed around y=0. From https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html, the $residual.scale produces a scalar giving the square root of the dispersion used in computing the standard errors.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `predict()` method for `zeroinfl` (and `hurdle`) objects does not have an `se.fit` argument at the moment. If you want to explore this, you would either have to use Monte Carlo methods (by drawing from the distribution of the coefficient estimates) or see whether the `zeroinfl` method in package [`lsmeans`](http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v069.i01) can be leveraged for your purposes.